# PostGIS: How to return polygon nearest the point

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL / PostGIS database 1  polygon and the other point data
How do I modify the following query so it returns only the smallest polygon nearest the point
The red in the picture
[image]

QUERY

```
select pt.point_id, ply.polygon_id,ply.admin_level
from point_table pt
join polygon_table as ply
on ST_WITHIN(pt.geometry, ply.geometry)
WHERE pt.point_id = 13424428  -- To Test  only
```

The above returns

```
point_id    poly_id admin_level
13424428    -1627120    10
13424428    -295351 8
13424428    -180837 6
13424428    -151336 5
13424428    -58447  4
13424428    -62149  2
```

I need only  the first row for this point in polygon with admin_level 10

**EDIT**
This Query will form a link table to join the point to it’s nearest parent polygon
It will look something like this, there could be multiply points  in the same polygon

```
point_id    poly_id admin_level
13424428    -1627120    10
13424429    -1627120    10
13424430    -1627120    10
13424422    -1627121    4
13424423    -1627121    4
13424434    -1627121    4
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ST_Distance(...) LIMIT 1` would do it, but only for a single point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right: "so it returns only the smallest polygon nearest the point", you can ORDER BY the size of the polygon (or another criterion you choose) and then return only the first record:

```
select pt.point_id, ply.polygon_id,ply.admin_level
from point_table pt
join polygon_table as ply
on ST_WITHIN(pt.geometry, ply.geometry)
WHERE pt.point_id = 13424428

ORDER BY ST_AREA(ply.geometry) LIMIT 1
```

(The last line is what's added to your query).

-- Update --

There may be other ways. But to find the polygon for each point, one way is to use `first()` aggregate function in PostgreSQL, which is defined [here](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/doc/first_last_agg.html) and requires installing a new PostgreSQL extension. If you can install the extension, then you can GROUP BY the id of the points and then take the `first` polygon out of each group based on the `ORDER BY ST_AREA(ply.geometry)`:

```
select pt.point_id
   , first(ply.polygon_id ORDER BY ST_AREA(ply.geometry))
   , first(ply.admin_level ORDER BY ST_AREA(ply.geometry))
from point_table pt
join polygon_table as ply
on ST_WITHIN(pt.geometry, ply.geometry)
GROUP BY pt.point_id;
```

I haven't verified this but I think something along this line will work for your data.

You can probably use sub-queries as described in [this related DBA.SE question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24327/55439). It's not exactly the same, but close.

Comment: As stated the WHERE clause is only there to test how do I scale it up if this removed please see Edit

Comment: @Holly I've updated the answer according to your edits. Note that it requires a non-standard aggregate function `first` as described in the link.

Comment: This could also be implemented without the aggregate library, just by using `row_number() over(partition by point.id order by ST_Area(...))` and restricting to the first ordered value for each point.